# How is it possible to apply the lazy approach to update a segment tree if the update is more complex than simple addition or multiplication?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree, range-query, lazy-propagation

Consider [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-trees-product-of-given-range-modulo-m/) question. In this segment tree solution, we are updating all nodes of the tree in the given range. Is it possible to apply [lazy propagation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lazy-propagation-in-segment-tree/) to this problem?

Edit: Consider that in every update operation `arr[i] = (1-(1-arr[i])*a)`, where `L<=i<=R` and `a` is a constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume your query operation is finding the sum in a range `[L, R]`.

You certainly want to do this efficiently, probably in `O(log n)` per operation.

You need a way to store data in the `lazy` field that allows you to compute the updates when traversing the tree for a query.

Let's see if we can write the update in a nicer way:

```
v = 1 - (1 - v) * a
  = 1 - (a - av)
  = 1 - a + av
```

If we do this twice:

```
1 - a + av = 1 - (1 - [1 - a + av]) * a
           =  1 - (a - a + a**2 - a**2 v)
           = 1 - a + a - a**2 + a**2 v
           = 1 - a**2 + a**2 v
```

Which is equivalent to (applied to an entire range):

1. Multiply by `a`
2. Subtract `a`
3. Add `1`

When updating the lazy field, it's clear that you just increase the exponent of `a`.

You can do all of these 3 lazily as described in the lazy propagation article you link to.

So your update operation can be split into 3 lazy updates, each done in `O(log n)` time, for a total time of `O(log n)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is indeed possible, at least in some cases.

Basically, you need a way to efficiently store the lazy operation, and a way to efficiently combine two stored lazy operations into one.

For instance, say the update operation is segment assignment, that is, `a[l] = x`, `a[l+1] = x`, `...`, `a[r-1] = x`, `a[r] = x`.
This operation on the whole subtree can be stored as just the value `x`, which will mean that the operation was to assign `x` to every vertex of this subtree.
For lazy propagation in vertex `v`, we just apply it to immediate children of vertex `v`, and store the same lazy operation `x` there.
Note that any old lazy operation in children is just erased by the assignment.
Such is the nature of assignment.

---

As for your added example, operation `arr[i] = (1 - (1 - arr[i]) * a)`, let us see how the value changes after two such operations with constants `a` and `b`.

Before operations, let the value be `v`.

After the first one, it becomes `w = 1 - (1 - v) * a`, which is `a*v + (1-a)*1`.

After the second operation, the value becomes `1 - (1 - w) * b`, which is `b*w + (1-b)*1`, which in turn is `b*a*v + b*(1-a)*1 + (1-b)*1`, and finally becomes `(b*a)*v + (1-b*a)*1`.
(I may have mixed up +s and -s, but that hopefully does not change the whole picture.)

We can now see that the value is a linear function of the original value, so we can store the coefficients `b*a` and `1-b*a` of the linear and constant terms, respectively.

The problem now is that the coefficients may grow too quickly, and will soon exceed the capacity of the storage type (`int`, `double` or whatever).
Now, if the problem deals with integer residues modulo some integer instead of just integers or reals, that's not an issue; otherwise, storing the coefficients soon becomes problematic.